# C import #defines from header file

Tags: c, xcode, macros

I'm using Xcode to develop little C command line tools and I have a header file that looks like this:

```
#define Bool unsigned char;
#define YES ((Bool) 1);
#define true ((Bool) 1);
#define NO ((Bool) 0);
#define false ((Bool) 0);
```

In another .c file I'm importing the header file like so

`#include "Definitions.h"`

Whenever I use `Bool` or `true` or `false` Xcode gives me the following warnings:

> Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
>
> Declaration does not declare anything

For a function like so:

[image]

If I take out the `include "Definitions.h"` and just put the defines in the c file all the warnings go away.

What is going on here?

Comment: Home-brew Boolean types are usually a bad idea. Use `stdbool.h`.

Answer (score 5):

Remove all the semi-colons from your `#define` statements!

Beyond that, there is no need to define these types. They are already there in `<stdbool.h>` which gives you `bool`, `true`, and `false`.

Comment: Ahh **** I am a noob. Thanks.

Comment: @RASS  and you should use `typedef` for type definition, shouldn't use `define`